# Why this MPI_SENDRECV is deadlock?

Tags: fortran, mpi

this is my first post. Thank you in advance for your kind help. This is a very short code for testing MPI_SENDRECV,which I did not understand. But it is deadlock can anybody tell me why?

```
 PROGRAM sendrecv
  INCLUDE "mpif.h"
  INTEGER ibuf(20)
  CALL MPI_INIT(ierr)
  CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, nprocs, ierr)
  CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank, ierr)
  a=1
  b=2
  if (myid == 0) then
     call mpi_sendrecv(a,1,mpi_real,1,0,
 .                     b,1,mpi_real,1,0,
 .                     MPI_COMM_WORLD, status,ierr)
  elseif (myid == 1) then
     call mpi_sendrecv(b,1,mpi_real,0,0,
 .                     a,1,mpi_real,0,0,
 .                     MPI_COMM_WORLD,status,ierr)
  end if
  if (myid.eq.0) then
     write(*,*) a
  endif
  if (myid.eq.1) then
     write(*,*) b
  endif
  CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ierr)
  END
```

Comment: One: you use `myrank`, but later check `myid`. Two: is `nprocs` > 2?

Comment: @SteveBlackwell -- good point about `myrank`/`myid`.  This is why `implcit none` is useful.  why does `nprocs>2` matter?  Maybe I'm just not seeing that...

Comment: In Fortran programs, always write `IMPLICIT NONE`.

Comment: @Steve Blackwell Yes you are right, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @SteveBlackwell, you're using `myid` instead of `myrank`.  If you use:

```
CALL MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ierr)
```

instead then you'll be halfway there.  The deadlock arises here because both processors (probably) have `myid = 0` (Note, this behavior is compiler dependent -- other compilers might set it to some strange number and your program will appear to work, but no messages will be passed).

Your second problem is that `status` is implicitly declared as a real variable, but MPI is expecting an integer array with size `MPI_STATUS_SIZE`.  This could have all sorts of effects -- You could get a segfault, or worse, some strange memory error since MPI is writing to a buffer that it shouldn't.  (alternatively, you could use `MPI_STATUS_IGNORE` since you're not doing anything with the status anyway).

As pointed out by @HighPerformanceMark, it is best practice to explicitly type everything in your program and use `IMPLICIT NONE` to avoid these types of problems.  In other words, you should have a really good reason if your subroutine/module/function/main program don't have an IMPLICIT NONE in the declaration.

Comment: Much better would be to drop `myid` altogether and stick with `myrank`, or to drop `myrank` and use `myid`.  Having 2 names for the same thing is only going to confuse, as the question indicates.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark -- Of course.  I was merely providing an explanation of what was wrong.  Anyway, I've added a line stating that the the user should change them to use the same name.  Good comment.

Comment: I corrected the code and now it works now, thanks gays , I do not believe myself that I can get help soon after I posted the question, I am really moved,I am suck at programming. Thanks for your time!